# SumIf gives answer without decimals

Tags: vba, excel, sumifs

I'm using VBA to sum the values of the cells within my SumRange given that they are positive numbers. The code works, however, it is not returning an answer with decimal places when it should have them.

```
RecebimentosValor = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(SumRange, ">0")
```

Comment: `RecebimentosValor` should be declared as `Double` or `Single` data type to hold the decimal places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure to use **Double:**

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim SumRange As Range, RecebimentosValor As Double
    Set SumRange = Range("A1:A10")
    RecebimentosValor = WorksheetFunction.SumIf(SumRange, ">0")
    MsgBox RecebimentosValor
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I see no problems with

```
Sub M_snb()
 y = [sum((A1:A12>0)*(A1:A12))]
 y = Application.SumIf(Range("A1:A12"), ">0")
End Sub
```

Comment: This way `y` is implicitly a `Variant` data type. It will work as well. But it is always better if this type can be avoided.

Comment: There's no valid reason to avoid a variant variable. Otherwise they wouldn't have been invented nor introduced in VBA.

Comment: If you've been coding for a long time, you'll realize that there are advantages and disadvantages of using variant data type. As for a well structured routine, it is always best to know the type of data you're working on. This will help you anticipate and control more runtime errors and would be easier to debug and maintain. That is the time you'll realize that the disadvantages out weighs the advantages. Well that is for me, I'm not saying that it is true to all.

Answer (score 0):

Not always. It depends on your input. If your input in decimal format then
output will be produce in Decimal form. Simple mathematics rule.